# How to send a voice command to amazon lex with android studio in java?

Tags: java, android-studio, speech-to-text, amazon-lex

I am using amazon lex under android studio. I tested sending text and it works perfectly. I would like to try sending a user's speech but I don't know how to go about it

```
AWSCredentialsProvider credentialProvider;
    String accessKeyId = "";
    String secretAccessKey = "";
    credentialProvider = new StaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKeyId, secretAccessKey));
    AmazonLexRuntimeClient client  = new AmazonLexRuntimeClient(credentialProvider);
    client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_2));
    PostTextRequest textRequest = new PostTextRequest();
    textRequest.setBotName("");
    textRequest.setBotAlias("");
    textRequest.setUserId("");
    textRequest.setInputText("");
    PostTextResult textResult = client.postText(textRequest);
    Log.e("AMAZON", textResult.getMessage());
    Log.e("AMAZON", textResult.getSentimentResponse().getSentimentLabel());
```

Here is my code for sending text to amazon lex.

Comment: Hi Uriel, Please edit your question and translate "Voila mon code pour l'envoie du text à amazon lex" to english

Answer (score 0):

Voice input can be sent to Lex using the SDK's `PostContent` method.

Here's the Java SDK reference for this method: - [AWS Lex Java SDK - PostContent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/lexruntime/AmazonLexRuntime.html#postContent-com.amazonaws.services.lexruntime.model.PostContentRequest-)

Comment: Please can you send me code example with android studio?